# Environment variables in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

I have a github project with my Jenkinsfile used for deployment, actually managing only the dev environment.

I'd like to manage the production environment as well, and some parameters would differ from dev to production.

Is it possible to manage this through the same Jenkinsfile, or do I need to create a separate Jenkinsfile to manage the prod settings in it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use environment specific variables in one Jenkinsfile with [Declarative Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/). If you configured your Jenkins pipeline to accept parameters using the **Build with Parameters** option, those parameters are accessible as members of the `params` variable.

Assuming that a String parameter named "DEPLOY_TO" has been configuring in the Jenkinsfile, it can access that parameter via `${params.DEPLOY_TO}:`

```
 environment {
    ...
    DEPLOY_ENV = "${params.DEPLOY_TO}"
    ...
}
```

You can differ this variable between your environments  while creating that environment's build job with the same Jenkinsfile.